# Looking for a good point to start customizing the Chisel source for rocketchip generator

Tags: scala, riscv, chisel

I've installed the riscv toolchain, and generated the verilog source with the default configs using the rocketchip generator source in the master branch at https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket-chip.

I'm looking to understand the chisel source so I can try out modifications on the Chisel source, and I'm not sure how I should get started with this.
For example, in the src/main/scala/TestConfigs.scala file - line 87 has the following code-

```
    class WithPrefetches extends Config(
      (pname, site, here) => pname match {
        case "COMPARATOR_PREFETCHES" => true
        case _ => throw new CDEMatchError
      })
```

I'm curious about why COMPARATOR_PREFETCHES is allowed as a case, and I'm trying to figure out what is "allowed" and where I can see these "definitions".

A push in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The place to start is `src/main/scala/Configs.scala` (TestConfigs.scala is used for generating test structures, not the actual processor).  There are many examples present of how to generate various flavors of Rocket.  As a concrete example, let's say you wanted to modify the default core to remove the FPU and increase the DCache associativity.  You could write:

```
class MyBetterCore extends Config (
    topDefinitions = { (pname,site,here) => pname match {
      case UseFPU => false
      case _ => throw new CDEMatchError
    }},
  knobValues = {
    case "L1D_WAYS" => 8
    case _ => throw new CDEMatchError
  }
)

class MyBetterConfig extends Config(new MyBetterCore ++ new BaseConfig)
```

Then you could build and simulate this core by setting the `CONFIG` command-line variable:

```
make CONFIG=MyBetterConfig
```

All of the parameters that are safe to modify out of the box are located in `Configs.scala`.